# manage custom listView with images in android cache memory

Tags: android, html, caching, listview, imageview

I am taking the reference of already ask question 
[Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

I want to manage all of this image data of listView in application cache memory not in HashMap. all the images are coming from server.
just like in Android market that is holding that data in cache memory and we can clear that from 
android Settings> applications> Manage application> my-application.

so how to manage this custom listView?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to do so because that cache is located in the internal directory and is not good enough to store downloaded images because the cache should not exceed 1MB. It is best to store the images in the SD Cards.

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html